# Add the name of the list to the tooltip when hovering over the unsave button

Tags: feature-request, tooltips, saves

I noticed that when I hover over the "Unsave" button a tooltip appears that currently just says: "Unsave this question." I want that the tooltip should also mention the name of the list from which this item will be removed. That is, the tooltip could be changed to say something like: "Unsave this question from ListName."

---

Below is the screenshot showing the **current tooltip**:

[image]

---

Below is the screenshot of the **modified tooltip** that I want it to change to:

[image]

In the above modified screenshot, I've highlighted the added text in *RED* so that it is more easily visible. While implementing this, the text would actually be the same color as the remaining text(black).

Comment: Somewhat ancillary, is there a distinction between removing something from one list and removing it altogether from your bookmarks? Can you have a question bookmarked in multiple lists simultaneously?

Comment: @TylerH Actually once I was trying to remove a save **answer** and when I hover over the unsave button I noticed that the tooltip did not tell me anything about the lists from which that answer will be removed. So originally I thought about the feature for an "answer". But then when I took the screenshot, I used a question. I don't think it should matter if we're removing an answer or a question from a saved list. Regardless, the tooltip should mention the list(s) from which that post(question/answer) will be removed.

Comment: My question doesn't really depend on whether you're talking about a question or an answer, actually... just curious if you can have a post (any post) in multiple lists at once or just one. If you can only have it in one, then that limits the usefulness of telling you what list it's in when you are hovering there to remove it.

Comment: @TylerH Even if it is in one list I want to know which is that list. For example, I have many lists and each of those have many posts. Suppose I visited SO after few days(like 100 days) and then suppose I came across a post that I've saved in one of my list. Now I realize that I want to say move this post from the old list to some new list. But i don't remember the name of the old list.So instead of manually checking each list or using some query or search box like `inbookmarks:...` etc, I want that the tooltip automatically tells me which list the post is in so that I can directly go to that.

Comment: OK, so the motivation sounds little misguided in that case. I would recommend an adjustment to the feature request here. Hovering over the save button of a saved post should instead say "This post is saved to `<ListName>`. Click to unsave it." with a confirmation modal appearing asking "Are you sure you want to unsave this post? You can re-save it later if you change your mind" or something.

Comment: However, my point is, if you can save a post to multiple lists, then how does it know which list to remove it from in your desired outcome? If it just removes it from all, how is it supposed to be implemented? I would _expect_ clicking that button to unsave it from _all_ lists, which means it wouldn't be possible to tell you about a specific list that it's on.

Comment: @TylerH Replying to your first comment(where you suggested what the tooltip should say): My point is about the tooltip mentioning the names of the list(s) where the post is saved. You(the implementor) can change the text inside the tooltip to whatever you like and find most suitable. It's just that I want the named of the list(s) to be included in that tooltip. Whatever else(text) you want to insert there is your choice. I just gave an example of one such text(that came to my mind and seems the most simplest) in my question.

Comment: @TylerH Replying to you second comment(where you're asking about "how does it know which list to remove it"): Then maybe a big tooltip can be shown. SO already have many big tooltip, so adding making this tooltip adapt to the number of list isn't  a big deal. Or maybe it can just mention any one of the list among the list of lists. But I would prefer a addaptive/responsive tooltip which can adapt according to the number of lists which have the post saved so that that bigger tooltip can mention all the lists.

Comment: @TylerH: [Currently, we are only allowing a post to be saved to a single list.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves).  I interpret that to mean that it could change some day.